# Flex - Easy way to set border on image

Tags: image, apache-flex, border, flex-spark

Is there an easy way to add a simple border to an image?

I'm loading in image thumbs, and would like to add a border at runtime, instead of having to edit all the thumbs.

I'm using Spark Image.

Thanks!

EDIT: 
I need to add a 1 px white border around these thumbs. I set the size of the tumbs to be 90x90, to make them fit if they are either horisontal or vertical, but the actual images in my example scales down to 90x51 (this is not fixed, only 90x90 as a maximum is fixed)

This is my code for adding thumbNails to a TileGroup (loading the gallery from an xml file):

```
private function loadPopUpThumbs():void{
            if(curThumbImg <= totThumbImg){
                var thumbImg:Image = new Image();
                var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
                var imageNr:int = curThumbImg;
                var thumbContainer:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();

                _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,function(e:Event):void{ 
                    thumbImg.source = e.currentTarget.content;
                    popUpImgGroup.addElement(thumbImg);

                    thumbImg.width = 90;
                    thumbImg.height = 90;
                    thumbImg.scaleMode = "letterbox";
                    thumbImg.verticalAlign = "bottom";
                    thumbImg.smooth = true;
                    thumbImg.id = "thumbImg" + imageNr;

                    //thumbImg.drawRoundRect(0,0,thumbImg.width,thumbImg.height, null, 0xffffff);

                    thumbImg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(evt:MouseEvent):void{
                        popUpThumbClicked(imageNr.toString());
                    });

                    trace("Thumb added: " + popUpXMLList.(attribute('nr')==imageNr.toString()).@thumbURL);
                    curThumbImg++;
                    loadPopUpThumbs();
                });

                _loader.load(new URLRequest(encodeURI(popUpXMLList.(attribute('nr')==imageNr.toString()).@thumbURL)));

            }else{
                trace("DONE Adding thubs!!!");
            }
        }
```

Also: Would it be possible to add a linebreak in the items added to the TileGroup?
In my XML file I've defined a group attribute, so that I'm able to devide the images into groups. If I click a image from one group, I can skip next/prev within that group, but not to the next group. Is there any way for me to insert a linebreak to my TileGroup, so that I can listen for when the prevGroup != curGroup, and then add in some sort of spacing before continuing adding the next thumbs? All I need is a way to skip a line in the tileGroup :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new custom Image Class, extends spark Image. Very simple and clean. And set border size and color with css. See example:

```
package classes
{
    import flash.display.CapsStyle;
    import flash.display.JointStyle;
    import flash.display.LineScaleMode;

    import spark.components.Image;

    public class ImageBorder extends Image
    {

        public function ImageBorder()
        {
            super();
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight); 

            if (imageDisplay && imageDisplay.bitmapData)
            {
                var borderSize:Number   = getStyle("borderSize") || 0;
                var borderColor:Number  = getStyle("borderColor") || 0xffffff;

                var half:Number = borderSize/2;
                imageDisplay.left = imageDisplay.top = imageDisplay.right =  imageDisplay.bottom = borderSize;

                graphics.clear();
                graphics.lineStyle(borderSize, borderColor, 1, false, LineScaleMode.NONE, CapsStyle.NONE, JointStyle.MITER);

                graphics.moveTo(0, half);
                graphics.lineTo(unscaledWidth -half, half);
                graphics.lineTo(unscaledWidth - half, unscaledHeight-half);
                graphics.lineTo(half, unscaledHeight-half);
                graphics.lineTo(half, half);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In application use with css:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    @namespace classes "classes.*";

    classes|ImageBorder 
    {
        borderSize : 10;
        borderColor : "0xff00ff";
    }

</fx:Style>

<classes:ImageBorder source=" your source url " />
```

Comment: Thanks! Will give it a try now :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but there is still one problem. I do define the width and height to be 90 px, but that is to make sure no image will be outside those bounds. If the image is horizontal then it is about 90x51. If it's vertical it's 51x90. Thats why I have the letterbox scale property.  How do I make the border only go around the actual image, and not make a 90x90 square border?

Comment: Ok, i update code, try it pls. If you want the border only go around the actual image, you can find actual resize width and height and draw custom border with lines

Comment: The border is still 90x90. http://screencast.com/t/piV45a5le6L  I will see if I can modify this to get the actual image content sizes. Let me know if you know the answer. Thanks a lot for the help so far mate! I'll accept it soon, when I get it to work 100% :)

Comment: This worked: graphics.drawRect(0, ((unscaledHeight-imgH)-borderSize),imgBD.width, imgBD.height);

Answer (score 0):

Spark image is a `SkinnableComponent`.

1. You can create your custom skin that supports borders in any
   convenient way, like styles or properties.
2. Or you can set that
   skin if you want to see border or remove it if you don't want
3. Or you can put it inside `BorderContainer`, and set `borderVisible` to
   true when you want to see the border.

Comment: borderVisible is not available to me when I create a BorderContainer and add the image as an element. Only borderStroke (which I do not know how to use).

All I need is a 1px white border around my images. =)

Comment: I've updated my question to include the code I've made to add thumbNails. I need the stroke to be around these thumbs.